# Random bluescreens probably because of Visual Studio 2013 network driver addons.

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

In the last few days I'm facing bluescreens at random moments. From 10 to 30 minutes. STOP 0x0000007F (UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP). The first paramater is always 0x00000008  -  Double Fault.

I've done a lot of research but could not find anything. There are 2 files causing this, of them is always

ntoskrnl.exe
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl

and the other one is one of these 3:

NDU.sys
http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/windows-8-338/awareness-thread-windows-8-memory-leak-ndu-sys-4309046.html

ndis.sys
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1764143/ndis-sys-causing-issues.html

fwpkclnt.sys
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-system/unexpectedkernelmodetrap-fwpkclntsys-blue-screen/f5ac1f62-583a-495e-a300-e464ef0a8ee3

VS2013 installed a lot of network drivers for the Windows Phone Virtual Machine. I can get rid of VS2013, but I don't wanna reinstall windows (is 8.1). The laptop is a week old and it will be gift.

Comment: Hmmm... If the laptop is only a week old I would consider that there could be a real hardware problem somewhere.

Comment: activate driver verifier, wait for the next crash, open the Memory.dmp with Windbg and run **!analyze -v**. Now post the output.

Comment: Thank you @PMF, but I'm not sure I understand this output. Here it is:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12120809/output.txt

Comment: you need to fix the symbols: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us

Comment: No need for now. Had to reinstall. After the next restart it couldn't even open windows. Another bluescreen, saying that driver verifier was violating sth. But thanks.